# Filter rows based on values of a column

Tags: r, filter, statistics

Here's the sample dataset:

```
sample  <- data.frame(ID =  c(100,100,101,101,102,102,103,103), flag = c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0))


   ID flag
1 100    0
2 100    0
3 101    1
4 101    1
5 102    0
6 102    1
7 103    0
8 103    0
```

I would like to filter the rows, based on the value in **flag** column, and keep only the **ID**s for which "all" the corresponding **flag** values are *0*.
In this case, the remaining rows are 1, 2, 7, and 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tidyverse` solution:

```r
# Load packages
require("tidyverse")
#> Loading required package: tidyverse

# Generate data
sample  <- data.frame(ID =  c(100,100,101,101,102,102,103,103), flag = c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0))

# Filter based on flag.
sample %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(all(flag == 0))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>      ID  flag
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1   100     0
#> 2   100     0
#> 3   103     0
#> 4   103     0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>